# Google MLKit Face Detection works on iPhone 6s but not iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, google-mlkit

I'm using Google's MLKit for Face Detection on iOS with Swift. I've followed the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios). The code from the guide worked on my iPhone 6s, however it doesn't work on my iPhone X. It turned out having to do with the imageOrientation function. In my capture session, I orient the image so that the pixel data matches the expected orientation (UIImage.Orientation.up). I verified this by inspecting the image inputted into MLKit through the debugger. As expected, the imageOrientation function on my 6s returns .up, however for my X it returns .leftMirrored. To temporarily work around this problem I hard set the visionImage.orientation to .up however it still doesn't work on my X. I also tried all the other orientation options and none of them worked.

Below is the relevant code from the class I created. Any suggestion for what I may be doing incorrectly?

```
    public func detect(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position, completion: @escaping (Face?) -> Void) {
        let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
        visionImage.orientation = .up //imageOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDevice.current.orientation, cameraPosition: cameraPosition)
        
        faceDetector.process(visionImage) { faces, error in
            guard error == nil, let faces = faces, !faces.isEmpty else {
                print("NO FACES FOUND")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            print(CACurrentMediaTime() - start)
            
            let face = faces.first!
            self.computeKeypoints(fromFace: face)
            
            completion(face)
        }
    }

   private func imageOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation, cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> UIImage.Orientation {
        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .portrait:
            return cameraPosition == .front ? .leftMirrored : .right
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return cameraPosition == .front ? .downMirrored : .up
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return cameraPosition == .front ? .rightMirrored : .left
        case .landscapeRight:
            return cameraPosition == .front ? .upMirrored : .down
        case .faceDown, .faceUp, .unknown:
            return .up
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I filed a bug report for this at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160361316.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to derive the image orientation based on whether you are using the front or the back camera.  See a working example of our quickstart sample app here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample/CameraViewController.swift#L888

This works on iPhone X.